# How to stop Java FX (1.8) menu button items from being drawn over the menu button?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have this really annoying problem with the Java FX menu button. I have an application that dynamically (at run time) adds items to the menu button menu. The menu button is positioned on the bottom of the screen and so the menu opens towards the top. The menu items are added at the bottom of the menu list. The problems is sometimes this causes the menu to be drawn over the menu button when it is clicked, eventually it will correct its self but since the menu has dynamic items it will happen repeatedly. Is there a way to force a recalculation of menu positions so when it opens it does not cover the menu button?

[The diagram on the left is what I would like to have happen when the menu is opened. The diagram on the  right is what actually happens when the menu is shown after adding a menu item (the whole menu is drawn on top of the menu button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaHnx.jpg)

Comment: No one has this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you come up with the solution?